# File URI in IE has stopped responding

Tags: web-server, internet-explorer, html

In our office we have a web server that has a very basic set of webpages.  Recently the File URI has just stopped responding for many people.  When you click on the link, nothing happens, IE does not try to load or give any kind of error message.  It acts like there is no link there. So now they have to right click and choose "Save Target as" if they want to access the documents on these webpages.  We have made no changes to the Site, and the site has been working like this for 4 years now.  We are absolutely stumped as to what could have caused this.  This all started happening on Monday and slowly more people are starting to become effected by it.

We've tried the following

1. Many Computer restarts
2. IE Compatibility Mode
3. Reset Internet Explorer Settings
4. The way the file URI is setup, does not working other browsers so that wasn't really an option.
5. Tried switching out the machine, worked at first then stopped working.
6. Save target as option works fine which leads me to believe there isn't an issue with the code or accessing the location.

If there is a better place for this question, please let me know.

Not sure if this helps, but this is the code:

`<a href="\\Servername\location$\subfolder\document.doc">document</a>`

Comment: Can you explain in more depth what you mean by this statement: "Recently the File URI has just stopped responding for many people"

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize that I forgot to include what was happening.

Comment: Have any updates been installed on the server or the clients?

Comment: No server updates. I will check to see if any of the clients have had any updates installed, but they shouldn't have.  One of the clients I was working on I did update from IE9 to IE10 to see if that would fix the issue but didn't, and we do have a mix of IE8, IE9, and IE10 machines that are working.

Comment: There have been no server updates or client updates when this issue started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that somehow the security zone associated with your Intranet or the file server got changed.

IE will not permit you to open content from a less-secure zone for reasons of security.  So if IE things your Intranet is in the 'Intranet Zone', and your  file server is in the 'Internet Zone', then you will not be able to follow the link automatically, but you can open it in another tab, or with a right click.

Check what zone the web page is in, and what zone IE things the file server is in.

Comment: This was it, I updated the GPO and everything started working again.  Thank you for your help.